# Terraform - Aws ssm resource creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating an tls_private_key and ssm parameter resource using terraform and storing the value of the private key in the ssm as string , the value in the ssm is bit weird and strange , it is completely missing but not sure what i am missing any help is much appreciated , thanks

```
resource "tls_private_key" "host" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "ssh_name" {
  name  = "/SSH/Host/KeyName"
  type  = "String"
  value = aws_key_pair.host.key_name
}
```

How it looks in Aws web console

Value

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAlgfShTSGzWpxazSD7Yr1TmhLOs1bFWwUDzEVFNeqNIjT/cfg nMjzMpnltBjFtRmjYRC6iA+8CnLnxwvDDd8TILlPgi/hgkj+AogYIi6wM02PgojA 1hHYFvmPnEVJCWlYqnxSzHjdTXGym7Xs7BvKN/lHd64A3lP0NujUTa/4G4ScdoO/ MyjFv9Suw0i/W2IBXSfquhOBPtOwGlhmgm/SeXGbKru9JlgC5FB7IAal6O2wfeYv
JzRafvcH46qmq+EdnHgkMZlsGo4qmcM7v5EfS7SOcfA0YuCtUedKYCKztVnDrEeE RxQtoYC2rwkLeZ4HAsU8xlEJZHkCVpCV84LLHns6+42E7zgyfi9Zlnf5poCO -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

$ cat test.pem

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAqDyIYMb+8W31Y/g6XDY711Xbtm7d9+i5Vspwr/XFQc/CDW4L
W0t9cVL9vvKbcIBVgaQVAN0BKGeScYkSvVt+Nu1eg1BZePdILhXRTUH+QzIvaUgp
2EwD5zGKBHKexi6/YSC5QIp/nuGdqiQ7RS2gwoqztoNAGx97G42ZJ+9DuGJRv5Eo
X54O5AHUkgIlHRlIj/N3xPORBCWqsRZXY05zUZf8IS3XNYIpBke4OLzfwS7B5QE3
bNhlHGBXk31eTmTdQZBL9i0ODB2I8zS2Ftk09dtLPfPoQcDcZIibvLbR4IRd
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

C:\>aws ssm get-parameter --name "/SSH/Host/PrivateKey"
aws ssm get-parameter --name "/SSH/Host/PrivateKey"
{
    "Parameter": {
        "Name": "/SSH/Host/PrivateKey",
        "Type": "String",
        "Value": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAqDyIYMb+8W31Y/g6XDY711Xbtm7d9+i5Vspwr/XFQc/CDW4L\nW0t9cVL9vvKbcIBVgaQVAN0BKGeScYkSvVt+Nu1eg1BZePdILhXRTUH+QzIvaUgp\n2EwD5zGKBHKexi6/YSC5QIp/nuGdqiQ7RS2gwoqztoNAGx97G42ZJ+9DuGJRv5Eo\ne0ECkdRynHKs9qtHYlrVShhfnkVUs/uKlrMZziHAVPK8hK11YWzBH8XP/719vpVI\n3RyVR0ohIREMJBtwS8xEfHnqDjgYFyExrdcMiCyXWAWA08SSi8p9WF8Bb8j41UFK\nqkx/usMj/wcmI+hfYgMimNUwwv1Q6kiqLwg0Cti
```

clearly i did not have an idea on this , i tried terraform multiple times , it still same

Comment: That value is exactly what an RSA key looks like. What were you expecting it to look like?

Comment: thanks mark, i modified the question with the output i am expecting , what is happening now is i have to copy the value from ssm and change the indentation and paste in my local with correct format and have to start working on it , i like to avoid this

Comment: It looks like it's just removing the newlines in the AWS web console. That's typical of displaying values in a web browser. Instead of copy/pasting out of the web console, what happens if you use the AWS API to retrieve the value? For example with the AWS CLI tool?

Comment: from cli i get pretty much the same way mark

Comment: Do you see those `\n` in the CLI output? Those are literally the newlines missing from the web console. You need to use the CLI to output that value to the file.

Comment: yes that works from cli , but just curious when storing in ssm parameter using terraform cant that be stored as expected ??

Comment: It is stored as expected. It is literally stored exactly as it should be, with the newlines intact. It just isn't being displayed with the newlines in the web browser, because web browsers don't display newlines in raw text that is embedded in HTML, and in the CLI output it is encoded inside JSON, so again it is being displayed appropriately in the JSON output.

Comment: thanks for educating me , just wondering why it is not stored as expected , thanks mark